# How to detect high contention critical sections?

Tags: winapi, debugging

My application uses many critical sections, and I want to know which of them might cause high contention. I want to avoid bottlenecks, to ensure scalability, especially on multi-core, multi-processor systems.
I already found one accidentally when I noticed many threads hanging while waiting to enter critical section when application was under heavy load. That was rather easy to fix, but how to detect such high contention critical sections before they become a real problem?
I know there is a way to create a full dump and get that info from it (somehow?). But this is rather intrusive way. Are there methods application can do on the fly to diagnose itself for such issues?
I could use data from structure _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG, but there are notes that this could be unsafe across different Windows versions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/01/434648.aspx
Can someone suggest a reliable and not too complex method to get such info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about makes perfect sense during testing, but isn't really feasible in production code.

I mean.. you CAN do things in production code, such as determine the LockCount and RecursionCount values (this is documented), subtract RecursionCount from LockCount and presto, you have the # of threads waiting to get their hands on the CRITICAL_SECTION object.

You may even want to go deeper. The RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG structure IS documented in the SDK. The only thing that ever changed regarding this structure was that some reserved fields were given names and were put to use. I mean.. it's in the SDK headers (winnt.h), documented fields do NOT change. You misunderstood Raymond's story. (He's partially at fault, he likes a sensation as much as the next guy.)

My general point is, if there's heavy lock contention in your application, you should, by all means, ferret it out. But don't ever make the code inside a critical section bigger if you can avoid it. And reading the debug structure (or even lockcount/recursioncount) should only ever happen when you're holding the object. It's fine in a debug/testing version, but it should not go into production.

Comment: Of course, this isn't for production code, this is a debugging thing.
I'm not asking for advices how to improve synchronization to avoid contention. I can handle that. I'm asking for help in determining what needs to be optimized. I have dozens of critical sections. Some of them are rarely used, others maybe are subject to contention. I want to put application under stress tests and see which critical sections are bottlenecks.
So, you say that RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG is documented. Do you mean it in SDK headers? Because I can't find it in MSDN documentation.

Comment: Can you confirm that RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG.ContentionCount has the same meaning since Windows XP till Windows 7?

Comment: It's in the SDK headers (winnt.h) and the definition does not change based on the target version set. You're safe to use it.

Comment: As for documentation, there are articles all over the 'net that explain the fields.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This field is internal, and while it is "documented" in winnt.h -- these fields are not something you should rely on. I caution you because in Windows 8 these fields  throw an Access Violation.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to handle concurrency besides critical sections (i.e semaphores).  One of the best ways is non-blocking synchronization.  That means structuring your code to not require blocking even with shared resources.  You shoudl read up on concurrency.  Also, you can post a code snippet here and someone can give you advice on how ways to improve your concurrecy code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Intel Thread Profiler. It should be able to help to spot such problems.

Also you may want to instrument your code by wrapping critical sections in a proxy that dumps data on the disk for analysis. It really depends on the app itself, but it could be at least the information how long thread been waiting for the CS.

Comment: Thread Profiler is powerful tool, but I need a lightweight method, without instrumenting the whole code.  
I think I'm gonna use RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG.ContentionCount.